# Why doesn't my class implement the interface despite having a defined event?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am currently learning about events having the following code:

```
public interface INotifyMessageChanged
{
    public event EventHandler MessageChanged;
}

public class Academy : Organization, INotifyMessageChanged
{
    public event EventHandler? NotifySubScriber;

    private string message = "";
    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { message = value; MessageChanged(); }
    }
    public Academy(string name, string address) : base(name)
    {
        Address = address;
    }

    void MessageChanged()
    {
        NotifySubScriber?.Invoke(this, nul);
    }
}
```

The code produces the following error:

```
CS0535  'Academy' does not implement interface member 'INotifyMessageChanged.MessageChanged'
```

Shouldn't the event MessageChanged in the interface correspond to the one in the class?

Comment: FYI: The new-ish feature of "_interface default member implementations_" aside, an interface is a contract of what APIs/members a type implementing that interface _has_ to provide. Note that not the interface provides the implementation of the members specified in the interface, a class implementing the interface has to provide the implementation. In the INotifyMessageChanged, `event EventHandler MessageChanged` is just a specification for a `MessageChanged` a class implemnting the INotifyMessageChanged interface has to implement. Which your class Academy doesn't, hence the error...

Comment: (Of course, with the new-ish feature "interface default member implementations", an interface can be written with default implementations for its members where and when it would make sense, relieving types implementing the interface from the hard requirement of needing to provide an implementation for those interface members. But for events, that would largely only be meaningful if the event specified in the interface would proxy other events the interface or another interface inherited by the interface specifies.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event signature is not the same, and neither is their name: `EventHandler MessageChanged` and `EventHandler? NotifySubscriber`

```
public interface INotifyMessageChanged
{
    public event EventHandler? MessageChanged;
}

public class Academy : Organization, INotifyMessageChanged
{
    public event EventHandler? MessageChanged;

    private string message = "";
    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { message = value; this.OnMessageChanged(); }
    }
    public Academy(string name, string address) : base(name)
    {
        Address = address;
    }

    void OnMessageChanged()
    {
        this.MessageChanged?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is still being produced whether I make them all nullable or not

EDIT: Made it work with your example - thanks!